# Is there a specific Datatype I can use for x-www-form-urlencoded parameters in c#?

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, content-type

I am working on a `Web-API` and i am receiving a `POST` request with a body with the `Content-type` as `x-www-form-urlencoded`

With this I am able to process the request but the dictionary is always empty for some reason. Is it because I am using the **wrong** datatype?
Or is there something else that is not right?

```cs
    static List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(Dictionary<string,string> value) //why is the dictionary empty?...
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in value)//keyValuePair
        {
            strings.Add("Key = " + kvp.Key + ", Value = " + kvp.Value);
        }
    }
```

I dont know if this can help but i also have this in my `WebApiconfig.cs` file so it returns in `application/json`

```cs
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I also want to apologize if this question is not that good or lacks certain information. I will try to add everything you need. Just give the word.
Thank you!

EDIT:
Post request sent to my api.

HEADER

```
host: localhost:60509
Accept: application/json,*/*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)
X-Slack-Request-Timestamp: 1568976729
X-Slack-Signature: v0=3fb0dda35d6925cabc393dabf3525ec998a755837316e5019e53a86c900f6651
Content-Length: 381
Connection: keep-alive
```

the only thing I can change is the host.

Comment: use `FormDataCollection`  instead `Dictionary` ... it's even implemenaing `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` so you don't have to change rest of the code :)

Comment: @Selvin It is working perfect with fiddler(thank you so much!) but the request I get from the app is not really giving a good response. (403_client_error) But I thik I can figure that out somehow